# Does this matrix have to be row reduced in order to have a pivot column?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider this matrix:
$$\left[
       \begin{array}{cc}
       1&1\\
       1&1\\
       \end{array}
\right]$$
So I understand that there is one pivot column when it is row reduced to this:
$$\left[
       \begin{array}{cc}
       1&1\\
       0&0\\
       \end{array}
\right]$$
But does this mean that the **original matrix** itself also has a pivot column? Or does that matrix have to be row reduced in order to have one?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a *pivot column* is what is also called a *basic column* (a basis column, a base column etc). In the context of row reduction, the term may refer to both some columns of the original matrix and those of the reduced form. For example, consider

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\boxed{\boldsymbol{1}} & 2 & \boldsymbol{3} & 4\\
\boldsymbol{2} & 4 & \boxed{\boldsymbol{5}} & 7
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 3\\
2 & 5
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\boxed{\boldsymbol{1}} & 2 & \boldsymbol{0} & 1\\
\boldsymbol{0} & 0 & \boxed{\boldsymbol{1}} & 1
\end{array}\right],$$

where on the lhs we have the original matrix, and on the rhs its RREF (Reduced Row Echelon Form). The boldface columns on the both sides are the basic columns, or the pivotal columns. Such terminology makes sense to me, at least.

---

P.S. Here is a kind of "sophistic" argument. Row reduction is a multi-step process in which you transform a matrix. At all the intermediate steps your matrix is neither the original, nor the end result. Moreover, there are moments at which you've determined which element shall be the next pivot, but haven't yet used it to further transform the matrix. If the concept of a *pivot column* makes sense at such intermediate steps, then it must also apply to both the original and the reduced matrices.